# Finding genus of projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Can anyone help me in finding the genus of the curves

a) $x^2y^2-z^2(x^2+y^2)$

b) $(x^3+y^3)z^2+x^3y^2-x^2y^3$

c) $y^4+z^4-2x^2(y-z)^2$

d) $y^2z^2-x^4-Y^4$

e) $(x^2-z^2)^2-2y^3z-3y^2z^2$

Here all the curves are homogeneous and I know genus is bounded by $(d-1)(d-2)/2$ and if these are non-singular then the values are exactly same. But I am not still very much handy with these conception so can anyone please help me with explanation how deal with these problems.

Comment: this is not a homework problem. I was trying to solve Fulton's Algebraic curves 8.14 and stuck in the first problem and my conception is not being cleared unless I see some worked out example here so if you can give me detailed solution of a few of this then I can try the rest or you can give me some problem after giving solution of these. Please help o.w I am not getting any application of this theory.

Comment: If you are using Fulton's book, I think he has the following sketch in mind: 1. Find the singular points of the curve, e.g. by computing where the Jacobian is zero. 2. Figure out their multiplicities. 3. If the singularities are ordinary multiple points, use Prop. 5 in §8.3.